# Bash script not working with double quotation

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, jenkins

When I run the script below it works fine but I have to enter the PublicDNS in the script. This script has single quotes.

```
          sh '''
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
        -i my-key.pem \
        ec2-user@ec2-xxx-xxx.amazonaws.com \
        "sudo yum update -y && \
        sudo yum install docker -y && \
        sudo systemctl start docker && \
        sudo docker pull image/test:be && \
        sudo docker run -d -p 8080:8080 image/test:be"
'''
```

However, when I try to add a variable for DNS in the second script and as a result change the script to double quotations then error shown below is thrown

```
sh """
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
        -i my-key.pem \
        ec2-user@$DNS \
        "sudo yum update -y && \
        sudo yum install docker -y && \
        sudo systemctl start docker && \
        sudo docker pull image/test:be && \
        sudo docker run -d -p 8080:8080 image/test:be"
"""
```

Error:

/var/jenkins_home/workspace/script.sh: 3: sudo yum update -y &&         sudo yum install docker -y &&         sudo systemctl start docker &&         sudo docker pull image/test:be &&         sudo docker run -d -p 8080:8080 image/test:be: not found

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You close the string on the next line: `"sudo`

Comment: But i do that when using single quotes too should it not throw an error then?

Comment: No, because `"` doesn't close a string between `'`. In addition, bash doesn't have tripple quotes like python to my knowledge.

Comment: So I tried to remove the " around the sudo commands and now I get the following error

sudo: yum: command not found

Comment: The argument to `sh` is a script filename, not commands to execute. You need to use `sh -c "commands"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a here-document:

```
sh <<EOF
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    -i my-key.pem \
    ec2-user@$DNS \
    "sudo yum update -y && \
    sudo yum install docker -y && \
    sudo systemctl start docker && \
    sudo docker pull image/test:be && \
    sudo docker run -d -p 8080:8080 image/test:be"
EOF
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how would i put this in a jenkins script?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Jenkins. This is just plain shell script.

Comment: I played around with it and it worked. Thank you very much :). Could you explain why this worked and what I had initially did not?

Comment: The comments explain the problem with your code. The quotes inside the string are matching the quotes you used to start the string.

Answer (score 1):

## 100% Working

Simply just use heredoc instead:

```
sh <<EOF
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
        -i my-key.pem \
        ec2-user@$DNS \
        "sudo yum update -y && \
        sudo yum install docker -y && \
        sudo systemctl start docker && \
        sudo docker pull image/test:be && \
        sudo docker run -d -p 8080:8080 image/test:be"
EOF
```